# Weird characters in Pixiedust jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pixiedust

I have an ugly display on the console when I try to debug using Pixiedust version 1.1.19. How to solve this please?[image]

Comment: I have same problem and not able to solve it.